# Using a global variable in two Projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Can i use a variable in 2 different projects (1 solution) without setting one project or other as DLL, just with declaring my variable in common.h that i will include in 2 projects?

Thanks

Comment: You can probably use environment variables `http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/`

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly: The link you provide is not recommended it is full of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking can you use a global variable to transfer data between two executables, then the answer is no. You also can't use it to transfer data  between two different dynamic link libraries.

Comment: Not two executables, between two .cpp that are in 2 different projects but in the same solution

Comment: That's an issue of Visual Studio, rather than C++, but if each project produces a different executable, the answer is still "no".

Comment: @A.Adil have you tried simply defining this variable in one .cpp and in .h declaring it as extern ?

Comment: No, they produce one .exe

Comment: @marcinj i tried but i have the error link LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Comment: @A.Adil have you properly setup dependency of one project on the other one? in VS this should be done using Project Dependencies

Comment: @marcinj no i didnt